# Setting the image of a Picturebox to the picture that the was clicked on form load

Tags: c#, picturebox

I had some trouble wording it in the title of this post so please looking here if you are confused on my question.
In the instance my question exists, my image viewer is the default for .jpg files. How would I go about setting the image of the picturebox to the .jpg file that was clicked?

I've researched a bit on how to do this but I haven't come up with anything and I believe it's because I'm not wording it right. Thanks in advance, Noah.

Also, if you need any other information or have questions, just ask.

Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top);
        this.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(this.Width - this.Width/2, this.Height -       this.Height/2);
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(300, 250);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs[0]);


    }
```

EDIT:
Added current code being used

Comment: A one-liner: pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs[0]);

Comment: @HansPassant I thought that's how it would work as well, doesn't seem to tho, get the following errors: http://puu.sh/5aQm5.png

Comment: The syntax is just slightly off.  Instead of `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs[0]`, it would be `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]`.  See the comments in my edited posted below, though, as the index is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The file that was double clicked will be passed to your application as a "command line argument".

You can retrieve that value using [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the Load() event of your form and load it into your PictureBox from there.

The executable itself is at index 0 (zero), with the argument at index 1 (one).

With that in mind, it should look more like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(args[1]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File: " + args[1] + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.ToString(), "Error Loading Image");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would I go about loading it into the PictureBox once I've retrieved the information?

Comment: Hans Passant gave you an example in the comments.  Please show your code so we can troubleshoot.